# Token collector objective

Tags: temple-run-2

What is "complete token collector" in Temple Run 2 at level 10? How do I complete it? I am not able to understand what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unlock one of the new characters (Cleopatra or Imhotep) if you have all their tokens. It took me a while to figure it out too.